# Citrus-Framework: How to wait for container to be healthy?

Tags: docker, integration-testing, citrus-framework

I'm starting and stopping containers which are used in multiple citrus tests. For that I need to ensure a container is up and running when a new test starts.
The docker images implement respective healthchecks.

Is there a way for citrus to wait for a container to be healthy/fully started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the wait test action (http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#actions-wait) which is able to wait for a Http GET to return 200 OK.